# How does static affect synchronized methods?

Tags: java

If a class has these two methods:

public static synchronized void m1() {}

public synchronized void m2() {}

Can two threads execute these two methods at the same time?

Comment: Yes. They won't be able to execute the _same_ method at the same time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, two threads can execute these two methods at the same time. The static method synchronizes on the class, the other method on the object itself.

In other words, a static method is an equivalent of this code block:

```
synchronized(MyClass.class) {
...
}
```

where `MyClass` is the class where the static method is defined. Note that it's not the same as `this.getClass()` in non-static methods as `getClass()` returns the most derived class.

Comment: @Makoto that answer is about two instance methods. Here you have an instance method and a static method, so yes, this answer is correct, as the static method has no instance to acquire the lock on.

Comment: @Makoto Turns out, the duplicate is not a duplicate - the situation is different here. One method is static, the other isnt.

Comment: @Henry:  Fair enough.  I'll change the dupe target.

Comment: ...So instead of looking for a *better* dupe, it's fine to reopen the question.  Okay.  I'll retreat for now, then.

Comment: @Makoto I found a better dupe.

Comment: So if i understood correctly, then if both methods were static they couldn't be executed at the same time. The same would happen if both of them didn't have the static modifier?

Comment: @user9871742 yes, this is correct.